# return floats to objective-c from arm assembly function

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, assembly, arm

I've written an assembly function that runs fine on an iPhone 4 (32-bit code) as well as on an iPhone 6s (64-bit code).  I pass in four floating point numbers from a calling function in objective-c.

Here is the structure I use for the 4 floating point numbers and below that is the prototype for the function - as found at the top of my objective-c code.

```
struct myValues{    // This is a structure.  It is used to conveniently group multiple data items logically.
    float A;        // I am using it here because i want to return multiple float values from my ASM code
    float B;        // They get passed in via S0, S1, S2 etc. and they come back out that way too
    float number;
    float divisor;  //gonna be 2.0
}myValues;

struct myValues my_asm(float e, float f, float g, float h);  //  Prototype for the ASM function
```

Down in my objective-c code I call my assembly function like this:

```
myValues = my_asm(myValues.A, myValues.B, myValues.number,myValues.divisor);   // ASM function
```

When running against the iPhone 6S the code runs like a champ (64-bit code).  The 4 floating point values are passed from the objective-c code to the assembly code via the ARM single float registers S0-S4.  The results returned are also passed via S0-S4.

When running against the iPhone 4 the code runs fine as well (32-bit code).  The 4 floating point values are passed from the obj-c code to the assembly code via the ARM single float registers S0, S2, S4, and S6 (not sure why skips odd registers).  The code runs fine but the values that get returned to my obj-c structure are garbage.

Where/how do i pass floating point values from the ARM 32-bit code so they arrive back in the obj-c structure?

thanks,
relayman357

p.s.  Below is my assembly code from my Xcode S file.

```
.ios_version_min 9, 0
.globl  _my_asm
.align  2

#ifdef __arm__
.thumb_func _my_asm
.syntax unified
.code 16

_my_asm:                   // 32 bit code
// S0 = A, S2 = B, S4 = Number, S6 = 2.0   - parameters passed in when called by the function
vadd.f32 s0, s0, s2 
vdiv.f32 s0, s0, s6   
vdiv.f32 s1, s4, s0   
vcvt.u32.f32 r0,s0
bx lr
//ret

#else
_my_asm:                  // 64 bit code
//add W0, W0, W1
; S0 = A, S1 = B, S2 = Number, S3 = 2.0  parameters passed in when called by the function
fadd s0, s0, s1  
fdiv s0, s0, s3  
fdiv s1, s2, s0  
ret

#endif
```

Comment: Write the equivalent C code and then disassemble it.   Somewhere in there you aren't meeting the needs of the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your functions are correctly returning a structure. You need to understand the ARM ABI. You can start by reading Apple's [iOS ABI Function Call Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Introduction/Introduction.html). If after studying the ABI you do not understand ask a new question showing what you've tried.

HTH

Comment: UPDATE:  Ok, I think HTH put me on the right trail - i’m just not quite there yet. Below is what i have managed to learn starting from reading the iOS ABI Function Call Guide.  Now i can access all the parameters passed to the asm code from within the asm code.  BUT, I still can’t successfully get the values out of my asm code back into my structure.

Comment: I changed my "myValues" struc to hold 6 floats.  The first 3 floating point values get passed to the assembly function via registers r1, r2, and r3.  Those are 32 bit registers and the values are encoded in IEEE 754 Single floating point format (in the Xcode debugger you can right-click on the register and select "view value as" and select float.  The remaining 3 floating point values that are passed from the calling code are pushed onto the stack and ready to grab with the following code in the assembly function:

Comment: Keys:
 1) Recognizing that the floats are stored in the 32-bit general registers (r1-r3) in IEEE 754 Single.  
 2) When debugging you can look at the general registers and right-click on "sp" and select "view memory of sp", then you have to change the viewed memory (for some reason it doesn't go to the memory address in sp) to the actual memory location stored is sp.  
 3) Once you are looking at the correct address:
  3a) The sp is pointing at the last value passed.
  3b) The values arestored in little endian - e.g. "00 20 00 40" is really "40 00 20 00" - which is float 2.002

Comment: // Add Prolog code here to play nice
  vmov s1, r1   // put IEEE 754 encoded 1st float in S1
  vmov s2, r2   // take the 2nd float and put in S2vmov s3, r3   
  vldr s6, [sp] 
  vldr s5, [sp, #4]   // load the 5th float into S5   (333.0)
  vldr s4, [sp, #8]   // load the 4th float into S4   (444.0)
  vdiv.f32 s3, s0, s0   //result S3 = 1.0  Change values
  vadd.f32 s0, s5, s3   // 334.0
  vadd.f32 s1, s1, s1   // 4.2
  vadd.f32 s2, s2, s1   // 9.438
  vstr s0, [sp]
  vstr s1, [sp, #4]
  vstr s2, [sp, #8]
  // Add Epilog code here to play nice

Comment: It is hard to follow but I think you're still failing to answer the obvious question: how can a function return a struct value which is larger than will fit in a register? Now there is more than one possible answer to that, can you think of any? Each ABI makes it own choice, if you can't find it in the docs tackle it a different way: write your function in Obj-C and disassemble it in Xcode and see how it returns the value.

Comment: Thank you.  I have figured out how to find the floats that are in the struct when my objective-c calls my asm code.   I can't figure out where to put the results in my asm code to get them back to the struct.  This is my first foray into objective-c (i'm not a "real

Comment: "real" progammer - i'm just a novice) so i'll see if i can figure out how to replace my asm function with an obj-c function and then look at the disassembly.

Comment: OK CRD, i'm closer.  Now i'm just passing a pointer to the first float value in my struct in to the asm code.  Before i call the asm code i get the pointer with this code,  "float* ptr2A = &myValues.A;".   When i step into the asm i see the address to myValues.A is in general register r1.  Sure enough, at that memory location i find the value i passed in for A.  The other floats are after it in memory.  So, i can get to all the structure values in my asm fine.  Now, how to i get those values back out?

Comment: I tried writing them back out like this: "vstr s3, [r1]".  I can verify that the memory address held in r1 has the correct float (in IEEE 754 single format) after the above line of asm runs.  But, when i step out of the asm code and back to the calling obj-c code the value of A is garbage.  I'm a little stumped.

Comment: Actually i use 2 lines of code to get the pointer before passing to my asm:  float* ptr2A = &myValues.A;
       myValues.ptr2A = ptr2A;

Comment: @relayman357 - It sounds like you've discovered the crucial bit that was missing: when a function returns a struct value it is compiled to accept an additional argument being a *pointer* to where the return struct value should be stored, and calls to the function are compiled passing the address of the struct variable into which the result needs to be placed. The ABI spec, or disassembling code, will tell you how this additional parameter is handled. You can of course make passing the pointer to the result explicit and have the fuction return `void` - see the `NSDecimal` functions for examples

Comment: @relayman357 - If having made the changes for the extra argument, either implicitly or explicitly passed, you cannot get your code to work then ask a new question showing the code you have written, describe the problem, and someone will probably help you out. HTH